# Return Java script code on jquery ajax response

Tags: jquery

I had to update the projects tree view on project status change with ajax. I used this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("#sel").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
                    type: "GET", 
                    url: "<my url>...&stat="+$(this).val(),
                    dataType: "script",
                    cache: true,
                    success: function(data) { 
                    $("#ajax_results").html(data);

                   }
                });
```

The html of result list:

```
echo "<div id='ajax_results'>";
          echo '<SCRIPT>initializeDocument();</SCRIPT></div>          
         </SPAN>';
```

The tree view uses this script: *http://www.TreeView.net*.
I need to get the tree, the above code, displays the js code generated by the file i called in URL. How can I do it, to execute the java script after ajax response for the tree to be displayed? 
Below are the print screens of projects tree view before and after status change.
[image: Before status change:]

After status change:

[image: After status change:]

I tried also this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("#sel").change(function(){
 $("#ajax_results").load('<my url>....&stat=all');
});
 });
```

It displays nothing at result list div.

Answer (score 0):

I believe jquery provides a facility for accepting script results:  `dataType: 'script'`

Comment: I tried that, no result showing at result list div. It returns the same js script (I saw with inspect element), but not showing it in div.

Comment: You could try getting the contents inside the script tags and use `eval`. I would really discourage anyone from using eval though. The need for eval is usually a sign of much bigger design problems.